# How can I "destroy" a draggable object, then re-enable it again?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that is draggable along the Y axis.  When the div hits 50px, I destroy  the draggable element, then preform a animation to move it back to the start, how can I enable the element to become draggable again once the animation completes?

here is a  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3h2Q/6/)

```
$( ".box" ).draggable({ 
    axis: "y",
    drag: function( event, ui ) {
        y2 = ui.position.top;
        x2 = ui.position.left;
        $('.result').text(y2);
        if (y2 > 100) {
           $( ".box" ).draggable('destroy')
           $('.box').animate({
               top:0
           }, {
               duration:500,
               complete: function() {
                   //$( ".box" ).draggable('enable');//doesn't work
                   $( ".box" ).draggable({axis: "y"});
               }
           })
         }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of tweaking user2436738's answer will work.

You just need to prevent the drag events from updating the position whilst you're animating the box back to its original position:

```
var reverting = false;
$(".box").draggable({
    axis: "y",
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        var y2 = ui.position.top;
        var x2 = ui.position.left;
        $('.result').text(y2);

        if (reverting){
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        } else if (y2 > 100) {
            reverting = true;
            revertDrag($('.box'));
        }
    }
});

function revertDrag(element){
    element.draggable('disable');
    element.animate({
        top: 0
    }, {
        duration: 500,
        complete: function() {
            reverting = false;
            element.draggable('enable');
        }
    })
}
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly_cardinal/F3h2Q/12/

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should rather do this:

```
object.draggable( 'disable' )
```

This will disable the object and it wont be draggable.

```
object.draggable( 'enable' )
```

After that you can re-enable the drag on the object.

Comment: I tried that, the results were not what i want. (i want a pull to refresh effect.) this is what happens with `disable` http://jsfiddle.net/F3h2Q/8/